# No pdf generated

Tags: jspdf

i use jsPDF and plugin jsPDF-AutoTable

I have a html table i want to print

```
$('#printFreeRoom').on('click', function (e) {
    freeRoomAvailableReport($("#freeRoomTableResult"));
});

function freeRoomAvailableReport(tableId) {

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
  doc.text("From HTML", 40, 50);
  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(tableId);
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
    startY: 60
  });

   doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
   doc.save('test.pdf');

}
```

nothing is generated when i click on the button.

I created a example on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8da5e1fj/

seem like a chrome problem...
tried other example: http://jsfiddle.net/8tLt9yof/10/ and get same result.

Comment: `$("#...")` returns an array. use `doc.autoTableHtmlToJson($("#freeRoomTableResult")[0])` (however, while that creates a test.pdf file, it does not load and does not appear to be a well-formed PDF file)

Comment: ok thanks, i took the html example of jsPDF-AutoTable and get same result with chrome.  no problem with firefox... strange

Answer (score 2):

You need to add FileSaver.js to use **doc.save()** also, Chrome has issues with `doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')`

Hence, here is a working fiddle for doc.save [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tLt9yof/16/)

And, to open the PDF in new window try this -

```
var blob = doc.output("blob");
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

Just an additional "Enter" on the browser address bar will show the PDF in chrome.

**UPDATE**

Longer URL's are not supported by Chrome as per [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478389http://jsfiddle.net/8tLt9yof/10/). Canvas in the fiddle is generating base64 URL which Chrome fails to load.

Comment: is there a way to avoid to do the enter to get it working?

Comment: Haven't went too far with that. But there's always a way! Go ahead and explore.

Comment: FileSaver.js is not needed for chrome

Comment: @roberttrudel Can you try running the code in the fiddle without FileSaver.js? Didn't worked for me. I am on Version 45.0.2454.99 m

Comment: with release: 44.0.2403.157 that work without fileSaver

Comment: @roberttrudel Ok. On the updated ones they might have ruled it out. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: will try tonigh on the version 45. have you tried the autoprint?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Even tried the --kiosk-printing solution. But neither of them worked.

Comment: Updated my answer with the new findings.

Comment: tried also pdfmake, same problem with chrome and firefox... seem imposible to print without dialog box....